# Asterisk* Originating a playback php script , but getting fwrite() broken pipe

Tags: php, asterisk

Hello I am working on Asterisk frame work, and I am writing a php script for which I could playback a voice message in meetme conference.

Somehow my php script returns this error:

```
ERROR[27555]: utils.c:1390 ast_careful_fwrite: fwrite() returned error: Broken pipe
```

Here is my php script:

```
<?PHP


set_time_limit(0);

$filename = $_GET['click'];

$socket = fsockopen("127.0.0.1","5038", $errno, $errstr, 10);

 if (!$socket) { echo "$errstr ($errno)\n";
echo fgets($socket).'<br>';}

else {
 fputs($socket, "Action: Login\r\n");
 fputs($socket, "UserName: myasterisk\r\n");
 fputs($socket, "Secret: *****\r\n\r\n");
 fputs($socket, "Action: Command\r\n");
// fputs($socket, "Command: sip show peers\r\n\r\n");
 fputs($socket, "Command: meetme(2500,p)\r\n\r\n");
 fputs($socket, "Command: Playback($filename)\r\n\r\n");
 fputs($socket, "Command: Hangup()\r\n\r\n");
 fputs($socket, "Action: Logoff\r\n\r\n");

 echo fgets($socket).'<br>';

 fclose($socket);
 }
error_reporting(E_ALL);

?>
```

Please see where I am making a mistake.

How can I run this script into my dial plan with 1st priority to enter meetme conference and then playback audio by executing this script?

Please help me it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that logout working correctly, it looks like that you are closing connection before logoff.

More details:

http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=75713

Update:

Probably issue is that you are not reading everything from AMI socket. Try following code for example:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

$filename = $_GET['click'];

$socket = fsockopen("127.0.0.1","5038", $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
fputs($socket, "Action: Login\r\n");
fputs($socket, "UserName: myasterisk\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Secret: *****\r\n\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Command: meetme(2500,p)\r\n\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Command: Playback($filename)\r\n\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Command: Hangup()\r\n\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Action: Logoff\r\n\r\n");
while (!feof($socket)) {
  $wrets .= fread($socket, 8192);
}
fclose($socket);
echo <<<ASTERISKMANAGEREND
ASTERISK MANAGER OUTPUT:
$wrets
ASTERISKMANAGEREND;
?>
```

Comment: can you tell me where exaclty i have to close the connection . i have tried all the possibilities but getting the sam error..  ???

Comment: i have tried all possibilities of closing the connection .can you please show any example where i can close it properly .